# Azure Table Query async - continuation token always returned

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, azure-table-storage, azure-storage

I am attempting to perform an asynchronous `TableQuery` against Azure Table Storage using `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync`. The relevent portion of the code is below:

```
public async Task<List<MyEntity>> GetTableData()
{
    CloudTableClient tableClient = GetTableClient();

    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("MyTableName");

    TableQuery<MyEntity> query = new TableQuery<MyEntity>().Take(10);

    List<MyEntity> results = new List<MyEntity>();
    TableContinuationToken token = null;

    do
    {
        var seg = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, token);
        token = seg.ContinuationToken;
        results.AddRange(seg.Results);
    }
    while (token != null);

    return results
}
```

The problem is that whilst `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` returns the correct number of records, the continuation token is never null, and the code loops continually.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I am using Windows Azure Storage 4.3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Basically you're fetching all entities from your table with 10 entities at a time (`new TableQuery<MyEntity>().Take(10)`). So in one call, table service returns you 10 entities and because there are more than 10 entities in the table (I'm assuming), it returns a continuation token and thus the loop continues.

Comment: Ah ok, so if I only wanted to return a total of 10 results do I need to keep a count in the while loop or is there a better query construct?

Comment: So if you want just top 10 records, you execute this loop once. Since you're fetching top 10 records (and not specifying a query), if you remove the loop in your code, you should be fine. If you were doing a query which could result in table service just returning continuation token, then you would need to maintain the count.